# Make sure another ip-address has access to a remote (linux) computer

Tags: linux, putty

I set up a remote computer with Linux (ubuntu) on it. Now im logging into from another computer using putty (SSH). Locally all works fine but now I would like to add another IP-address (one which is not local).

I already created a new user in Ubuntu but no I would like to somehow grant another ip address to access my remote server. I know this question is not well structured and all but I do not really have a clue where to start. Could anybody link me to some information about how to grant access to remote servers for different ip-addresses?

Comment: what protocol, SSH, telnet...? usually the default configuration allows everything so why not just try to connect with other computer.

Comment: If you are able to connect from `computer 1` to `computer 2` via putty (I want  to hope via ssh :-) )  that means that on `computer 2` is active a receiver (an ssh or telnet deamon, `sshd` or the deprecated `telnetd`).  This means that `computer 2` is able to accept connections from other computers, that are able to reach it. Exceptions: if there's a firewall, if they are on different private networks without a route between them, if the deamon settings deny connections from computer or networks unknown, if your are on a private network [home] and you want to reach this computer from outside).

Comment: Please spend some words more to describe the situation, the IP of the `computer 2` (maybe 192.168.1.xxx) `computer 1` and `computer new`,  the type of connection to internet they have... else it can be too wide to be answered. Please [edit] your post to have detailed and focused answers. You may want to give it a look here ([ask]), to help the others to give you an answer. ps> Welcome on superuser. PPS> __Simply: to be sure try :-) it__

Answer (score 0):

It seems a joke but it isn't: **try to connect with ssh to that computer from another one**.
It is the most simple way to know it. `:-)`.

### Some words more

I assume you have a *local network* where there is the `computer 1` (a windows one) and  `computer 2` (an Ubuntu with no special set up).

- They are connected in the same subnet.
- It is possible to log-in in computer 2 from computer 1 via SSH.
  This means that on computer 2 it is active an *ssh deamon*, probably `sshd` from the openssh-server package; (you can check it with `pgrep -l sshd` from a linux shell on the computer 2).

Now you have to see to which kind of local network your computers are connected:

1. **A network with public IP**: the subnet has public IP for each member.
   From the *new computer* you have to do only `ssh YourUsername@XXX.YYY.ZZZ.TTT` where the last is the IP of your Ubuntu machine.

   If you didn't modify anything, the *sshd deamon* is set to accept connections from each computer, not only the ones in the subnet.
   You have always to give the couple user/password to access. It is all already ok, you should only know the IP of computer 2.

   You can know the IP with `hostname -I` or read with `ip addr show | grep inet`...
   If it is an IPv4 <sup>[[IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4)]</sup> it will be something like `XXX.YYY.ZZZ.TTT`.

   You can start to read more about IPv4 <sup>[[IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4)]</sup> and IPv6 <sup>[[IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6)]</sup> for example on wikipedia.
2. **A network with private IP <sup>[[PrivateIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)]</sup>**.
   You have a local IP address and you will exit on internet with another one.

   You should have a router between your computer and internet.  Once you **set up the port forwarding** on your router to the Ubuntu machine, you will be able to connect from the *new computer* with `ssh YourUsername@XX2.YY2.ZZ2.TT2` where the last one is the public IP of your router.

   To know with which IP <sup>[[PublicIP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip)]</sup> you exit on internet you can run command like `curl ipv4.ipogre.com`, `curl ipv6.ipogre.com`, `curl http://smart-ip.net/myip`, `telnet myip.gelma.net`... or simply ask to google `my ip`, always from the Ubuntu machine.

   If you are out of the house or you cannot/wont search each time for your public IP,  you should **set up a dynamic dns service** <sup>[[DDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS#DDNS_for_Internet_access_devices)]</sup> search for a free one on your favourite search engine. At present, just for example, there is noip <sup>[[noIP](http://www.noip.com/free)]</sup>.

   **More details**
   <sup>Following the RFC1918 the local IP address can be numbers in the ranges:</sup>

   > 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
   >   172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
   >   192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255

   <sup>The most common situation is that your computers have IP numbers for example like `192.168.0.100` and `192.168.0.101`. Those are the local (internal) IP ones.</sup>

   <sup>You should have a router connected with the Lan of your provider that give you a *public IP* among the ones available. Usually it is the same one for each connection of the router (if it is a not so long connection), but it changes each time your router re-connects to the provider's net. If you pay, or if it is included in your contract, you can have always the same *external IP*.</sup>

   Read more on another answer of this site <sup>[[HowToSSH](https://superuser.com/a/69968/257269)]</sup> and on the manual of the router.